# Function in Math.Net like pcg in Matlab handles function

Tags: c#, math, solver

I would like to know if there is any function in Math.Net in C# having the same function as pcg in Matlab which is able to handle the A(x) = b, rather than Ax = b. Here, A(x) means A is a function of x, rather than A times x equals b.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think, there's any. A() is a function that MSL has no idea (ie. what to do inside the function). This is simple like you create a staic function for you and call it. But if you want something like, **Func<outputType, inputType>**, you can create your one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the documentation of Math.NET? There is page about how to [solve linear equations](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/docs/LinearEquations.html).

Comment: Thank you. I checked it but did not any clue. But I think my problem is not a linear problem, maybe I need other optimisation technique to estimate x. I will have a try.